# Adding Already Existing User to AAD tenant programatically

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, active-directory

I am wondering if there is a way to add already existing users in an AAD tenant to a different tenant programmatically? I can only see the powershell cmdlet for adding(creating) a new user in the same tenant. Basically this is the workflow that i want to automate:
On the Azure portal. i go to the tenant and then click on Add user
When i click on Add User it asks me to provide Type of User where i choose User in another Microsoft Azure AD directory.

Is there a way to programatically do this using some code in powershell or C# or some other microsoft stack?

Basically i want to achieve automation for steps mentioned in this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users-external/

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not directly supported. One way to add "O365 Management APIs" application and then use office.com admin portal to import users from a csv file. But this only works if the users on the same tenant.